# Continuous path of unitary matrices with prescribed first column?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, oa.operator-algebras, matrix-theory

Consider a continuous curve $u \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}^n$ where $u(t)$ is always a unit vector, $u(t)^* u(t) = 1$.

**Question 1**: Does there exist a continuous curve $U \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that $U(t)$ is always unitary and the first column of $U(t)$ is $u(t)$?

**Question 2**: Does there exist a continuous curve $U \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that $U(t)$ is always [lower-Hessenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix), unitary, and the first column of $U(t)$ is $u(t)$.

---

My thoughts:

(1) My guess is that the answer to both questions is yes, but I am unable to exhibit a path.  For question 1, one might try to perform Gram-Schmidt to construct $U(t)$, but it is not clear how to do this in a way that is always continuous.

(2) Lower Hessenberg unitary matrices are usually determined by their first column, but this is not always the case.  See the theorem below from "Orthogonal Polynomials on the Unit Circle, Part 1" by Barry Simon (which treats upper Hessenberg matrices -- but just take the conjugate-transpose): [image: attached]

(3) Feel free to assume $u(t)$ is smooth or even analytic.

Comment: For Question 1, I don't see anything discontinuous about Gram–Schmidt as long as you can restrict to a range where $u$ avoids a fixed hyperplane—say, $u(t)\cdot(1, 0, \dotsc, 0) \ne 0$.  But then can't you just break the domain into subintervals on the interior of each of which the condition is satisfied, and piece together solutions on each such subinterval?

Comment: Reasonable idea -- although it's not clear to me how to piece together the subintervals in a continuous way.  Related: I guess for Question 1, it would be enough to exhibit a continuous curve $X(t) \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ whose first column is $u(t)$ and such that $X(t)$ is always full rank [but not totally clear to me how to do this].  Then we could apply Gram-Schmidt to this curve.  No idea how to proceed for Question 2.

Comment: For Question 2: consider the matrix $X(t)$ whose first column is $u(t)$ and whose remaining columns are the basis vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_{n-1}$.  Then doing Gram-Schmidt on $X(t)$ should produce $U(t)$ which is unitary and lower-Hessenburg (since $X(t)$ is lower Hessenburg).  However, we still run into the issue that $X(t)$ may be rank-deficient for some $t$ (same issue as Question 1).

Comment: For the first question - what I will say is probably equivalent to what @LSpice says but the map from the unitary group to $\mathbb C^n$ mapping $U$ to $Uu(0)$ is a fibration onto the orbit of $u(0)$ which is the whole unit sphere. Being a fibration it has the homotopy lifting property, i. e. you can in fact continuously lift not only paths but any contractible chunks.

Comment: As for the secont question, the Proposition you reproduced suggests that you want to restrict this to a subset of the unitary group that is a torus (Cartesian product of $n$ circles). I would examine the resulting map from the torus to its image on the orbit, if it remains a fibration, the same argument applies. If not - I don't know.

Comment: If the function $u$ avoids the span of $e_1$ then I think I have an explicit construction that would give a positive answer to Q1. The idea/intuition is that if $u$ is any unit vector which is linearly independent of $e_1$, then one can define a unitary operator $R$ that rotates $e_1$ to $u$ and leaves each vector in $\{e_1,u\}^\perp$ fixed. Some back of the envelope calculations suggest that $R$ should be continuous as a function of $u$, but I need to check the details.

Comment: @YemonChoi Possibly what you were thinking of, the Householder matrix construction $U = I - (2/w^*w)ww^*$ where $w = e_1 - u$.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey Actually the Householder reflection was the first thing I thought of, but I was worried about singularities when $u$ approaches the span of $e_1$. Moreover, I was hoping to get a solution that would also work for the analogous problem in SO(n,R). I thought that my rotation idea (which yields matrices with determinant 1) could be made to work at the singularities but I am no longer sure if that is the case.

Answer (score 4):

Question 1: yes

As pointed out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459596/continuous-path-of-unitary-matrices-with-prescribed-first-column#comment1190880_459596) by @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, the map $U(n)\to S^{2n-1}$ taking a unitary matrix to its first column is a fiber bundle and therefore a fibration.

Question 2: no

Let $n$ be $3$. Make a path $u$ of unitary matrices such that for some $t_0$ the vector $u(t_0)$ is $(1,0,0)$, and such that for $t<t_0$ the vector $u(t)$ has the form $(a,b, 0)$ with $b\neq 0$, while for $t>t_0$ the vector $u(t)$ has the form $(a,0, c)$. The third column of the matrix $U(t)$ is required to have the form $(0,y,z)$ and also to be orthogonal to $u(t)$. When $t<t_0$ this means $y=0$. When $t>0$ it means $z=0$. This contradicts continuity of $U$ at $t=t_0$.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I meant to mention that. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!  Great answer!